# How do I load environment variables in Vue.js without webpack?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

The question has it all, but basically, I set up a new `vue` app without webpack. When I try to do:

```
handleSubmit() {
  axios
    .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}`)
    .then(response => (this.info = response));
  this.$router.push({ name: "ConversationsList" });
}
```

It's undefined. In my `.env` file, I have:

```
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

What do I have to do now?

Comment: The simple answer is "start using Webpack". The more complicated answer is "create your own little build tool to handle this functionality".

Comment: Can I start using webpack in my existing project?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: Can you share some pointers?

Comment: Since this is a new Vue app, I'd use `vue-cli` to generate a new project with Webpack, and copy your existing code into the structure it generates. Alternatively, you can use a new project as a guideline for what you have to do.

Comment: Are you currently building your app in any way? if you are using node you can use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to load your environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix. Created a file called `vue.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
                }
            })
        ]
    }
}
```